# Where are the files located after downloading from iCloud?

Tags: icloud, photos, ssd, external-disk, big-sur

I have a very limited storage of 256 GB on my MacBook Air and out of which the iCloud downloads the data on my local disk. However, I have an external SSD of 1TB and would like to store all the downloaded data to my external SSD and redirect the future downloads from iCloud to the SSD.

[image: Screenshot of the total storage space]

I see a 3.68 GB of data on my local hard disk, but not able to view the photos too. The only place I could see the data is on the **Finder** > **iCloud**. Will be helpful if someone could give a way to solve this.

P.S I am new to macOS and it runs Big Sur

Comment: If you're concerned about the library for Photos.app, close it, and then move the library to where you want it to be.  Then  open Photos.app again, and it will ask where the library is.

Comment: Btw, iCloud stores documents in `~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/`, and application specific folders in `~/Library/Mobile Documents`

Comment: I had a Mac Mini with a smaller internal drive too and just got a thunderbolt-connected external drive and moved my whole user profile to the external disk. This might be a bit clumsy on a laptop but I guess it depends on if you can put up with an external drive that needs to be always attached or not.

Comment: Logicer, I do not see a module with that name. Steve Chambers, by moving user profile, you mean /Users/<name>? I mean my biggest space is the brew thing and I installed Python that was linked to the PATH. If there is way to move that to the external one, do let me know. I have the thunderbolt connection too.

Comment: A python install shouldn’t be big enough to make a difference worth dancing it being installed on an external disk.  Unless the whole OS is actually there.